# YouTube Data API: video's title not in commentThreads endpoint result

Tags: api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube Data API v3 for my projects, and am wondering whether, from this API call:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=YOUR_KEY&textFormat=plainText&part=snippet&maxResults=5&order=relevance&videoId=YOUR_ID`,

can I get that video's title or not?

This is what I obtained from this API:

```json
    {
        "kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
        "etag": "KcqDjUnisqZz_7Kr1dfxHxM4jSM",
        "nextPageToken": "QURTSl9pMUxESzFEZk53RV9nNnUzRWx6S2VQY1A5QVpPS2JrZUltdnl2MzhidmM4bzRaY1ZTa1ZzaXBQbGdiYWd0LXRvc1lTVzJQSHdnLXdKRW11MzlDMHp1WGpFS1dCVEczb0hXZ3JhcEQ0b3FnVlprb1duRUJTWVh1d0J1dzVJdw==",
        "pageInfo": {
          "totalResults": 5,
          "resultsPerPage": 5
        },
        "items": [
          {
            "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
            "etag": "h3h5DKe5ApoaVan5iX4vC2glnYA",
            "id": "Ugxxqkvik0jDB9_WSth4AaABAg",
            "snippet": {
              "videoId": "8juRm9I__uk",
              "topLevelComment": {
                "kind": "youtube#comment",
                "etag": "pjDNsBFra34PxM9VOQtI49R9-_Y",
                "id": "Ugxxqkvik0jDB9_WSth4AaABAg",
                "snippet": {
                  "videoId": "8juRm9I__uk",
                  "textDisplay": "Nyesel beli realme 3 pro ",
                  "textOriginal": "Nyesel beli realme 3 pro ",
                  "authorDisplayName": "Dodi Satria",
                  "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnir7Yxd0qmDbKtLo568c7RKbDQvGlFeq_LjlGxM4A=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
                  "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC28fGIqdC7B1y5BRVhmI8Eg",
                  "authorChannelId": {
                    "value": "UC28fGIqdC7B1y5BRVhmI8Eg"
                  },
                  "canRate": true,
                  "viewerRating": "none",
                  "likeCount": 3,
                  "publishedAt": "2019-08-01T11:52:39Z",
                  "updatedAt": "2019-08-01T11:52:39Z"
                }
              },
              "canReply": true,
              "totalReplyCount": 1,
              "isPublic": true
            }
          },
```

The video ID is there, but can I get the title of the video?

Comment: you have the video id did you try doing a video get?

Comment: i did get the video, but how can i do that by one request? to be efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@DaImTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) suggested [with her comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66576393/youtube-api-data-comment-threads#comment117694766_66576393), you need to call the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint to get metadata info corresponding to the video you're interested in.

Here is a generic URL that, when issued on an `GET` HTTP method, invokes `Videos.list`:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=YOUR_API_KEY&part=snippet&fields=items/snippet/title&id=YOUR_VIDEO_ID`.

Do note that above I used the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) request parameter for to get from the API only the info that's actually needed.

As an example, in case of `id` being `bKINwXXzlaQ`, the endpoint returns the following JSON response text:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "snippet": {
        "title": "The European semiconductor industry and its global competition | DW News"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: so basically i can't do that in one HTTP request? i need to call comment API first and then  do the videos list request? @stvar

Comment: @Eranda Dava: Since you already have the ID of the video of your interest when invoking `CommentThreads.list`, you may well call `Videos.list` before calling `CommentThreads.list`; only that you'll have to have *two separate* API calls, one for each of the two endpoints.

Comment: @Eranda Dava: With respect to efficiency, note that the [quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) of one call to `Videos.list` is only 1 point (very cheap).

Comment: okay i get it, i thought i can call it in just one request. thank you for your answer

Comment: @Eranda Dava: Also note that you may well issue `Videos.list` with as much as 50 video IDs in one call: the request parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) is allowed to be specified as a comma-separated list of video IDs. Irrespective of the number of IDs passed on to the endpoint, one call of it is only 1 unit of quota cost.